# react native image from (http) doesn't appear after release to .apk

Tags: android, http, react-native

react native image from uri (http) can appear during debugging, but doesn't appear after release to apk and install on android phone.

```
<Image
      source={{uri: props.img}} //props.img value is 'http://example.jpg'
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        height: undefined,
        width: undefined,
        resizeMode: 'cover',
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginTop: 12,
      }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Amazing, Thank you so much !